# Ansible - jinja prevent jinja from stripping newlines in macro

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Assuming I have a jinja2 template using the following p

```
{% macro logging(ltype) %}
{% if ltype == 'fluentd' %}
logging:
  driver: 'fluentd'
  options:
    tag: "{{ app_name }}.{{ '{{' }}.Name{{ '}}' }}"
    labels: "mylabel"
{% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
...                                                                                                                   
   {{ logging('fluentd') }}                                                                                           
...
```

When I am rendering this template (`template` module), I am getting

```
...
   logging:
  driver: 'fluentd'
  options:
    tag: "test.{{.Name}}"
    labels: "mylabel"

...
```

As you can see, `driver` key is shifted for reasons unknown to me.
I have tried all whitespace control possibilities, nothing changes this behaviour.

Has anyone got an idea to fix it?

The desired result is

```
...
   logging:
     driver: 'fluentd'
     options:
       tag: "test.{{.Name}}"
       labels: "mylabel"   
...
```

Comment: Sorry, but a little confused here.  Looks like `logging` is shifted over, not `driver`, and your output seems to want EVERYTHING indented more than is in the template.

Comment: Exactly: logging exactly at the right spot, but driver got all the whitespaces stripped that it had in the macro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change that part of the template to:

```
...

{{ logging('fluentd') | indent(3,true) }}

...
```

Comment: Does not change anything - Everything is still indented wrong. (just three spaces more to the right)

Comment: Did you move it all the way over to the left in the template?

Comment: Not to my way of thinking.  All the macro does is insert that text at the exact location you put the macro.  If you remove from your original template the part that says `{{ logging('fluentd') }}`, then do a copy-and-paste of the macro lines to that location (with those same three spaces to the left), you will get exactly the same output that you got when you called the macro at that location.  A macro is just a copy-paste.